# Clojure: A program which seems to require heavy use of data structure mutation

Tags: clojure, functional-programming, tree, treeview, immutability

Let's say I have a list of vectors like this:

```
b
b a
b a b
b a b c
b a b c d
b a b c d 1
b a b c d 2
b a b c d 3
b s
b b
b b w
b b w a
b b q
b b x
b z
b r
b q
b q e
b q y
```

and I want to convert this list into a tree like structure. Every node can be represented with a map of two keys `:data` and `:children`. I'm trying to write a clojure method which would convert such a nested list into a tree structure and facing some trouble mainly because clojure doesn't provide mutable data structures.

Let's say I have a node which looks like this:

```
{ :data "b" :children #{...} }
```

Now if I want to modify a child of this node, I'll have to:

1. Modify that child (this is the only step one needs to carry out in other languages, but clojure will make a copy of that child and the node wouldn't be modified at all)
2. `dissoc` the old child from the `:children` set
3. `assoc` the new modified child to the set obtained in step 2
4. `assoc` the set obtained in step 3 as the `:children` of top node

In code it would look something like this:

```
(let [children (top-node :children)]
    (assoc top-node :children
        (conj (disj children node-to-modify) (modify-node node-to-modify))))
```

Isn't it overly complicated? Is there an easier way of doing this? Is there a more `functional` way of performing this task?

Comment: Why don't you use clojure.zip instead? This is my first choice for a task like this.

Answer (score 4):

as far as i understand, you are stuck with producing tree from list (am i right?)

in fact, you don't need any mutation to build this kind of tree. The simplest recursive way for that would be something like that:

```
(defn to-tree [data]
  (let [data (keep seq data)]
    (map (fn [[k vs]] {:data k
                       :children (to-tree (keep next vs))})
         (group-by first data))))
```

in repl:

```
user> (clojure.pprint/pprint (first (to-tree data)))

;;{:data b,
;; :children
;; ({:data a,
;;   :children
;;   ({:data b,
;;     :children
;;     ({:data c,
;;       :children
;;       ({:data d,
;;         :children
;;         ({:data 1, :children ()}
;;          {:data 2, :children ()}
;;          {:data 3, :children ()})})})})}
;;  {:data s, :children ()}
;;  {:data b,
;;   :children
;;   ({:data w, :children ({:data a, :children ()})}
;;    {:data q, :children ()}
;;    {:data x, :children ()})}
;;  {:data z, :children ()}
;;  {:data r, :children ()}
;;  {:data q,
;;   :children ({:data e, :children ()} {:data y, :children ()})})}
```

and to 'change' the values you can use [zippers](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.zip/zipper)

also, since your input is sorted in a certain way, you can optimize it a bit, using `partition-by` instead of `group-by`:

```
(defn to-tree [data]
  (let [data (keep seq data)]
    (map (fn [vs] {:data (ffirst vs)
                   :children (to-tree (keep next vs))})
         (partition-by first data))))
```